# Allow only specific users to unlock Tridion components and pages

Tags: 2011-sp1, security, user-management

I would like to give specific team to unlock the components and pages locked by others. It should be restricted to only components and pages.

Is there any way to do this without making them admins in 2011 Sp1 version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no other way out-of-the-box, but you could create your own solution (e.g. a Custom Page) which exposes this functionality to the right people. Behind the scenes it then needs to impersonate an administrator user to do the actions.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the locks being accidental or intentional you might try programmatically unlocking on a fixed schedule (like 04:00). If people lock items for a purposes you would not want them unlocked (even by an admin). Note that "unlocking" comes in two flavors: checkin or cancel checkout. Accidental locks should normally be cancelled but incidental ones should not (as they indicate valuable work-in-progress).

If none of the above applies you can of course go with Peter's excellent suggestion of a custom page although if there are so many accidentally locked items that you need a team of people to unlock I would suggest training your user community as well...